# Are there methods to learn a projection method into euclidean space, given a set of pairwise distances?

Tags: machine-learning, distance-functions, euclidean

Basically, right now I am trying to do some nearest-neighbour searching on an approach where I don't have points in Euclidean space.  To do a nearest-neighbour search currently, I take the query and compare it (with a special similarity function) to each model in the database to find the most similar one.

With this similarity function, I can compute pairwise distances between all points in my database, and I'm interested in whether it's possible to learn a projection into Euclidean space such that any new query can just be projected and nearest neighbour searches can then be performed in that Euclidean space.

Does such a method exist, or am I hoping for a holy grail that hasn't been solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Laplacian Eigenmaps, Locally Linear Embedding or Local Tangent Space Alignment. These methods map the distances in a low-dimensional space non-linearly, thereby preserving the local neighborhood/ local geometry. A very preliminary technique would be classical metric multidimensional scaling- but this would be a linear projection, and hence it is fairly possible that the local neighborhood is not preserved accurately, unless the intrinsic dimensionality of the data is low (one way of interpreting this is- the data can be represented as a kernel gram matrix, which has a low-error low rank approximation).

Comment: Thanks for this, but I`m either misunderstanding your response or you misunderstood the question.  These give us a projection based on a matrix of pairwise distances.  I can project my initial database into the space fine with this.  However, a new, unseen data point cannot be projected without comparing against the entire database with these methods, can it?  I want to avoid having to compare against the whole database for each unseen point

Comment: No. We are in the right direction. These methods have, what is called a "Out-of-Sample" embedding. Which allow for out-of-sample(new) data to be mapped, without requiring to map the entire, updated dataset all again.

Comment: Amazing.  I`ll have to do some more reading then, thank you

Comment: Sorry for bugging you, just one quick question :)  I'm trying to find a suitable LLE algorithm, and am reading "Truly Incremental Locally Linear Embedding", however, this still requires a full comparison of a new data point against all existing points for each new data point.  Do you have a recommended method or resource?  Thank you

Comment: Out-of-Sample Extensions for LLE, Isomap,
MDS, Eigenmaps, and Spectral Clustering- (NIPS)- Eqns 8 to eqns 12 and section 4.

Comment: Awesome, you've been really helpful.  Thanks a lot for this.  One final question that would logically follow is do you know of any implementations (preferably c++, but i`ll take what i can get) that support out-of-sample methods already?  I see some implementations of LLE (in Shogun, for example), but none seem to support out-of-sample embedding.  I can't say thanks enough, so thanks again

Comment: This is not a place for people to share code. Understand the paper and write it yourself.